# high CPU with high user connection, mysql database

Tags: mysql, linux, cpu, innodb

I use a VPS with 56 CPU cores and  64 GB of memory, a with MySQL database, but the CPU usage is always high for my apps - user 10.000.
This is in my `mysqld.cnf`. What's wrong with my settings?

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=50G
innodb_change_buffering=all
innodb_log_file_size = 3125M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 3125M
innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_log_files_in_group =4
innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 50
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_thread_concurrency=112
innodb_stats_on_metadata = OFF
innodb_thread_sleep_delay=1000
innodb_purge_threads=8
innodb_read_io_threads = 32
innodb_write_io_threads = 32
innodb_io_capacity = 5000
innodb_io_capacity_max=15000
key_buffer_size         = 4G
max_allowed_packet      = 1G
thread_stack            = 5M
sort_buffer_size = 50M
read_buffer_size = 50M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 20M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 20M
join_buffer_size = 1G   
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 1000
max_user_connections = 500
thread_cache_size      = 1000
query_cache_limit       = 0
query_cache_size        = 0
long_query_time = 10
expire_logs_days        = 5
max_binlog_size   = 200M
```

Comment: So what mysql version? What is your app doing? Why do you say its wrong? Can we see a `show global status` and `show processlist`?

Comment: What makes you say _CPU usage always high_? Are you just looking at load average? Is it IO related, as opposed to CPU? What are the slow query log and performance schema telling you?

Comment: What do you mean by user 10.00  ?  Is it 100% cpu usage ?

Comment: What Version of MySQL?

Comment: mysql version 5.7.4 when peak season max_used_connections = 155 thread_connection = 153

Comment: my global status https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XTi4X_7Uwe4uY_nsBjtaoqznazpQOre4/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 0):

`innodb_log_buffer_size` - I would keep that under 1% of RAM.  (`innodb_log_file_size` looks OK.)

`innodb_log_files_in_group` there is some evidence that more that "2" degrades performance.

`innodb_flush_method` -- this depends on MySQL version and disk filesystem type.  (Your choice is rarely picked by other DBAs.)

Did you also set `innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay`?  I see that MariaDB abandoned `innodb_thread_sleep_delay` in 10.5 -- either it was obviated by some improvement, or it was deemed not useful.  I don't know MySQL's stand on the two.

`innodb_io_capacity_max=15000` -- Do you have a super-duper SSD?

`key_buffer_size = 4G`:  Unless you are using MyISAM (you should not be), set this to only 50M.

`thread_stack` -- Leave at the default value

`long_query_time = 1` to make better use of the slowlog.  After a day, analyze it with `pt-query-digest`.  [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

But the real way to deal with high CPU (or Load Average) is to find the 'worst' queries (according to the slowlog) and work on improving them.  (Random tuning of settings can only get you into trouble.)

For further analysis of the settings, please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` and `SHOW VARIABLES;` after running at least a day.  ( http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning )

Comment: I saw some settings in the tutorial and asked on the forum, then how should the settings be

Comment: mysql version 5.7.4 when peak season max_used_connections = 155 thread_connection = 153

Comment: global status https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XTi4X_7Uwe4uY_nsBjtaoqznazpQOre4/view?usp=share_link

Comment: To analyze that, I also need `SHOW VARIABLES` and RAM size.  However, since that `STATUS` list was after only a few minutes, it will not tell us much.  `SHOW GLOBAL STAUTUS` after 24 hours would be better.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RGuCsoodCYueLG_WGazUdIemlsF2h3Lt?usp=share_link  , drive show_var and show global when cpu 100% high. if i reboot my server cpu auto high again if user that connect too much

Comment: Does it settle down after 4 minutes 33 seconds?  Do you have the slowlog turned on with a much lower value for `long_query_tmie`?

Comment: 23 Connections/second is moderately high, but not alarming.  1K qps - ditto.  17 Threads_running at the time you took the STATUS -- also high, but not alarming.

Comment: What are the clients doing?

Comment: absenteeism for employees, only 4 minutes because they are in absenteeism

Comment: Eh?  MySQL is restarted that frequently?

Comment: yes. exactly...